# How do I get node-inspector to run with foreman and nodemon?

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-inspector, nodemon

I have my heroku config vars in my `.env` file, so I have to use *foreman* to run my app locally. I need to debug using *node-inspector*, and I would like to not have to restart my app manually, so I would also like to use *nodemon*.

How do I use nodemon, node-inspector and foreman together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple really, just chain them all together in one command.

```
# start node-inspector in the background
$ node-inspector &

# make nodemon execute foreman with debugging options enabled for app.js with
## either
$ nodemon --exec "foreman run node --debug-brk app.js"
## or
$ nodemon --exec "foreman run node --debug app.js"
```

And you're done!